# Pages 5 - Bullets and numbering are not being copied

Tags: mail.app, pages, iwork

I have a Pages 5 document that contains a bullets list. When I try to copy the content of the document into Mac Mail the text is copied without the bullets. That behavioral is reproduced with numbering list.

Is there a way to copy that list with the bullets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. You can notify Apple that you would like this feature implemented using their Pages feedback page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html

By the way, in case you didn't know, copy-pasting to other iWork apps works fine - bullets and other formatting is preserved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From [OS X: Keyboard shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343):

<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>: Apply the style of the surrounding text to the inserted object (Paste and Match Style)

[image]